# How to prove the bound for Relative Round Off error

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point, machine-precision

Machine precision is defined as the smallest machine number ε. Anything smaller when added to 1 will be lost at roundoff.

Prove that ε is the bound for relative round-off error.

```
ε = b^(1−t), if chopping
ε = 0.5b^(1-t), if rounding
```

where b is the base of the computer’s floating point number system and t is the mantissa length.